# Convert time to epoch time and find the diifference between 2 timestamps

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to `grep` for start and end times and get the difference between the timestamps

Input File : Logs.txt

```
11.04.2018 09:21:35 aaaaa: start_time
13.04.2018 02:22:35 aaaaa: end_time
11.04.2018 10:45:00 aaaaa: start_time
11.04.2018 11:00:00 aaaaa: end_time
```

The script I have written is given below :

```
awk -F"[.: ]" '/start/{printf "%s:%s:%s,", $4,$5,$6} /start/{start=($4 * 3600) + ($5 * 60) + $6} /end/{print (($4 * 3600) + ($5 * 60) + $6)-start;start=""}' log.txt
```

The output i am getting is :

```
09:21:35,-25140
10:45:00,900
```

But this is wrong because its just taking the time , its not considering the date. So how can I solve this problem . How can i use EPOCH time using `awk` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your awk supports mktime() function, a gawk extension, try something like:

```
awk -F"[.: ]" '
/start/ {start = mktime($3" "$2" "$1" "$4" "$5" "$6);
    printf("%s:%s:%s,", $4, $5, $6);
}
/end/ {end = mktime($3" "$2" "$1" "$4" "$5" "$6);
    print end - start;
}' log.txt
```

If you want to add a condition to make sure the log file holds both start and end time, how about:

```
awk -F"[.: ]" '
/start/ {start = mktime($3" "$2" "$1" "$4" "$5" "$6);
    hms = sprintf("%s:%s:%s,", $4, $5, $6);
}
/end/ {end = mktime($3" "$2" "$1" "$4" "$5" "$6);
    if (start) {
        print hms end - start;
        start = "";
    }
}' log.txt
```

Comment: And can you just tell me how i can use conditional statement in this . for example , i need to run this script only if it has both start and end time ? any help on this ? @tshiono

Comment: I've added an option in the Answer pane. Now the script outputs the result(s) if and only if the log file has the set(s) of start and end time. I hope I'm answering your request.